# How much does it cost to run Westworld?

Tags: westworld-2016

From the settings to the elaborate technology used to create/maintain the hosts, this setup looks far more expensive to produce than one would expect it to get back- how can it turn a profit (I heard somewhere it costs $40,000 to visit but how many people have that kind of scratch to splurge on a theme park)?

Comment: A lot. A heck of a lot. Disneyworld/Land cost about $600m a year to operate.

Comment: From some of the conversations, the actual park is a secondary item to  an unknown main agenda...so it's possible it's a loss leader.

Comment: Mandatory quote: we spared no expense.

Answer (score 7):

In the original movie, the cost of visiting Delos was outrageously high, even in 197X money.

[Slashfilm has a look at the maps and contracts for attending in the new series](http://www.slashfilm.com/westworld-map-and-contract/) - a little under $100,000 a day. We must assume that that's a prohibitive cost, even in the show's world. But there's a LOT of millionaires in the world. So a smaller number of daily guests, countered by the far higher fee means it's probably at least breaking even.

There's certainly an idea that the parks are just private sector entertainment implementations for a larger set of planned uses.  A loss leader, yes, but also a public face to put on the technology for a future attempt to use it out in the public.

Comment: How long has the park been open?

Comment: @Valorum- several characters, including Ford (A. Hopkins), Lowe (Jeffery Wright) and the Man in Black (Ed Harris) have said Westworld has been up and running at least thirty years.